# Do I understand the consequence of the rep league data correctly?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

So, I'm over at the [rep league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/579/quarter/worldbuilding/2019-01-01) wondering how to keep my slim quarterly lead over Separatix... (OK, I was just curious.  No, really, I was just curious....) and noticed two numbers:

- Reputation change of 1+: 1,754 users
- Total reputation of 1+: 52,385 users

Does that mean that the number of people who swoop in on the social media currents, leave a (usually very poor) answer, and never return outnumbers we, the blessed of Glarnak, by 30:1?

- If so, what have we tried in the past to help people stick around long enough to gain a basic understanding of our limitations?
- If not, what do those two numbers really mean?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *this partially came about due to my haunting meta.WB for the last few days and realizing that the number of Main users to Meta users is probably, itself, 30:1.  Meaning that the number of all users to active meta users is about 900:1.  I've been wondering how to get more activity in Meta and now I'm wondering if I shouldn't ignore meta and focus on ideas for recruiting loyalty to Main.*</sub>

Comment: It's my busy season at work, I'll get my lead back later in the year ;)

Comment: 1+ means equal to or more than 1, right?  You get a rep of 1 by creating an account, even if you never answer or ask a question.  A lot of those "total rep of 1+" may never have left an answer at all, poor or otherwise.

Comment: Not really answerworthy: if I were you, I'd concentrate first on (continuing!) to educate all the New Persons what WB:SE is about & how it works -- a never ending task!; secondarily on recruiting even more New Persons; and then teriarily on educating all the Even More New Persons you've brought in as what WB:SE is about & c. I may be wrong, but I think meta is more for those folks with questions about the System itself. A quiet Meta with relatively few but very high quality queries allows for good ponderment and discussion. Thousands and myriades of people flocking here might muddy the waters?

Comment: Sorry to interrupt your work schedule @Separatrix : https://stackexchange.com/leagues/579/month/worldbuilding/2019-04-01/55743#55743 , Of course, the status quo so far doesn't cite specific figures for turnover - the old giving way to the new etc..

Comment: @Agrajag *Now the gloves come off!  It's on!  It's absolutely on!* :-)

Comment: @Agrajag. getting lucky at the start of the month isn't enough, you have to keep it up, week after week, year after year ;)

Comment: @Separatrix I need to take your advice or it'll end in divorce..... ;)

Comment: As long as you're looking at the "all time" board you're interpreting the numbers/ratio correctly but not necessarily the reasons behind them.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's more like the total amount of people actively participating in the last few weeks is about 1/30 of the total amount of all registered users.

I participated in the site very actively a few years ago, then I stopped for a while. During the time I was out I was not in the "users with a +1 rep change during the period" group, but that doesn't mean I was someone who came from a social media current to leave a poor answer and disappear.

Sometime later I was jonesing for a virtual score so I came back. Just kidding... I usually browse other SE sites and the hot network questions had some really interesting questions on display. Also, I like sciences and this site presents interesting, creative challenges that are answerable with them. I think exploring that side of WB may lure more nerds like me into the site.